# encode ,length of character and width of display in python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> line="你好".encode("gbk").rjust(10)
>>> print(line)
b'      \xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'
>>> print(line.decode("gbk"))
      你好
>>> print("你好".rjust(10))
        你好
>>> len("你好".rjust(10))
10
>>> len(line.decode("gbk"))
8
>>> len("你好".encode("gbk").rjust(10).decode("gbk"))
8
```

It is so strange that  len("你好".rjust(10)) =10 ,len("你好".encode("gbk").rjust(10).decode("gbk"))=8, encode and decode can shrink two character in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between bytes and code points. When you take the `len` of a `bytes` object, you get the number of bytes. When you take the `len` of a `str` object, you get the number of unicode code points.

`line` is a bytes object, composed of 10 bytes:

```
>>> line
b'      \xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'
>>> list(line)
[32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 196, 227, 186, 195]
>>> len(line)
10
```

When you decode the `bytes` to a `str`, the `str` is composed of 8 code points:

```
>>> line.decode("gbk")
'      你好'
>>> list(line.decode("gbk"))
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '你', '好']

>>> len(line.decode("gbk"))
8
```

The two bytes `b'\xc4\xe3'` get decoded to one code point:

```
>>> b'\xc4\xe3'.decode('gbk')
'你'
```

And the same goes for `b'\xba\xc3'`.

---

Note that code points are not exactly the same as characters. A code point might be a combining accent mark, for example:

```
>>> print(u'a\u0300')
à
>>> len(u'a\u0300')
2
```

Some combining marks [can be composed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) with another code point to form one code point. Indeed, that's the case with the example above:

```
>>> import unicodedata as UD
>>> UD.normalize('NFKC', 'a\u0300')
'à'
>>> len(UD.normalize('NFKC', 'a\u0300'))
1
```

However, not all combining marks can be so composed:

```
>>> UD.normalize('NFKC', 'a\u030b')
'a̋'
>>> len(UD.normalize('NFKC', 'a\u030b'))
2
```

So even if you normalize, you can not assume that the number of characters you see is the number of code points in the `str`.